# Rounded Polygons in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

There used to be a way to do masking tricks to create rounded polygon corners in Photoshop, but I can't seem to find anything for accomplishing the same trick in Photoshop CS6. Does anyone out there have a solution?

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Comment: Seems to be the case. I spent hours today trying to do it and finally gave up and opened up AI and did it in 10s. I still would love to know if there's a trick in PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be done with a layer mask over the vector shape.

Create your polygon, then load the layers selection by Command-Clicking (Ctrl-click on pc) on the vector mask (the thumbnail of the pentagon in the layers palette below).

[image: Pentagon with marquee selection]

Then go to Select>Modify>Smooth. Enter the smooth amount.

[image]

After that it's just a matter of creating a layer mask based on the now rounded selection.

[image]

Now you have your rounded polygon fairly quickly and easily. You could also manually edit the shape with by adding points and using the convert point tool, but that would involve a great deal more work.

Comment: What does it mean "_load the layers selection by Command-Clicking_"? How do I "_load the layers selection_"?

Comment: There is no tools at all in PS CC you're talking about. So it doesn't work

Comment: @Green Command/Ctrl click on the icon of the layer you want to edit in the layers palette. That will load a selection based on the shape you've clicked. Also I just tried it in Photoshop CC 2017 and every step still works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick, no more, but it gets the job done: give your polygon a stroke layer effect and align the stroke outside. With thicker strokes, the effect is rounded. No control over the roundness, though...

Answer (score 0):

there is an option for polygon (radius) click on the small arrow behind the shape button (: [image]

Comment: No. Edges are too rounded and you can't control it